# Create and write xarray DataArray to NetCDF in chunks

Tags: python-xarray

Is it also possible to create an out-of-core DataArray, and write it chunk-by-chunk to a NetCDF4 file using xarray?

For example, I want to be able to do this in an out-of-core fashion when the dimensions are much bigger and I thus cannot store the whole array in memory:

```
num_steps = 20
num_times = 100
#Create DataArray
d = xr.DataArray(np.zeros([num_steps, num_times], np.float32),
                 {'Step': np.arange(num_steps),
                  'Time': np.arange(num_times)},
                 ('Step', 'Time'))
#Computatation
for i in range(num_steps):
    d[i, :] = i
#Write to file
d.to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

So I don't want to have to create the whole NumPy array in memory, and I want the Computation and Write to file stages to be done one chunk at a time (chunked over the Step dimension in this example).

Update:
It seems (from @jhamman's answer) that it may not be possible to implement my example above using xarray. I am mainly interested in developing a greater understanding of out-of-core computation with xarray, so I do not have a specific computation that I am asking about, but, since I have been asked for a more complicated example, one potential application I have is:

```
for i in range(num_steps):
    u[:] = f(u)
    s[:] = g(s)
    d[i, :] = u[:] * s[:]
```

where `u` and `s` are xr.DataArrays of dimension Time, and `f` and `g` are PDE solvers that only depend on the input array from the previous step. Let's say there are 1000 steps, but the Time dimension is so big that I can only store one or two in memory, so assignments to `d` must be written to disk and then the associated memory freed.

Comment: Can you share more details about what your computation looks like? What is it doing and how many steps are there? What does the dependency structure look like between steps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, xarray supports out-of-core arrays and writing in chunks. You will need to write your computation using xarray operations and [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) arrays instead of NumPy arrays. The [xarray docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html) should be helpful here.

**Update**: For a simulation like this, you would need to compute each function `f` using [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html). Then you could convert the results in dask arrays with `dask.array.from_delayed`, wrap them back in `xarray.DataArray` and write the data directly to disk with `to_netcdf()`. The result proceeds in a streaming fashion, with `f()` and `g()` computed in parallel and no more than a few time-steps ever loaded into memory:

```
import dask
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import xarray

def f(x):
    return 1.1 * x

def g(x):
    return 0.9 * x

num_steps = 1000
num_times = int(1e6)

u = np.ones(num_times)
s = np.ones(num_times)

arrays = []
for i in range(num_steps):
    u = dask.delayed(f)(u)
    s = dask.delayed(g)(s)
    product = da.from_delayed(u * s, shape=(num_times,), dtype=float)
    arrays.append(product)

stacked = da.stack(arrays)
data_array = xarray.DataArray(stacked, dims=['step', 'time'])
%time data_array.to_netcdf('results.nc')
# CPU times: user 7.44 s, sys: 13.5 s, total: 20.9 s
# Wall time: 29.4 s
```

You'll notice that xarray is pretty peripheral to this computation: most of the computation was done with dask/numpy. You could easily do this with xarray objects, too, but we don't have a convenient way to pass labeled array metadata through dask delayed objects, so either way you would need to reconstruct metadata on the other side.

You could argue that using dask here is overkill, and you would probably be right. Even if you want to use dask for parallelization, you still probably want to check-point the simulation after each step in the form of a valid netCDF file.

So a simple loop that extends a netCDF file at each iteration is probably want you want. This is [not yet supported](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1672) by xarray but this would be a nice feature to have. Something like the following interface should be possible:

```
for i in range(num_steps):
    u[:] = f(u)
    s[:] = g(s)
    d[:] = u[:] * s[:]
    d.to_netcdf('results.nc', extend='step')
```

In the meantime, you could write separate files for each step, e.g.,

```
for i in range(num_steps):
    u[:] = f(u)
    s[:] = g(s)
    d[:] = u[:] * s[:]
    d.to_netcdf('results-%04d.nc' % i)
```

Then you could load all your data together and consolidate it into a single file afterwards using `open_mfdataset`, e.g.,

```
combined = xarray.open_mfdataset('results-*.nc', autoclose=True)
combined.to_netcdf('results-combined.nc')
```

Comment: I have read the docs you link to many times, but it is still not clear to me how to achieve what I describe (also, the blog post link in the docs is dead, it should be [this](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/xray-dask-out-core-labeled-arrays-python/?lang=en)). Even @jhamman was unclear about writing to NetCDF in chunks (see his answer), so perhaps the documentation on this topic would benefit from some clarification. I tried doing as I think you suggested, creating my xr.DataArray using a dask.array.zeros, but I ran into the problem of dask arrays not allowing assignment.

Comment: Joe is correct that you cannot do assignment with dask arrays. But it does support chunked writing of arrays more generally, when written with the dask library. It's hard for me to give more specific advice without understanding more about your underlying goal (see my comment on your first post).

Comment: I have updated my question with a more realistic example.

Comment: I added a large update, let me know if you have more questions

Comment: Wow, that's impressive - I didn't think it was going to be possible. Since the metadata is not propagated, it does seem like this approach might, as you say, be a bit overkill, though, so just using netCDF4-python, as @jhamman suggests, may be best, at least until xarray gains the ability to extend existing files.

Comment: Any update on this? Is extending netcdf available through xarray?

Answer (score 3):

Dask arrays do not currently support item assignment, see [Item assignment to Python dask array objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142892/item-assignment-to-python-dask-array-objects).

So this will not work if `d` is a `xarray.DataArray` with a dask.array under the hood.

<strike>Additionally, none of the current Xarray backends support chunked writes.</strike> EDIT: As @shoyer points out, it is possible to have xarray write chunked arrays incrementally. However, for your use case here, since you seem to need item assignment, it may be necessary to use the `netCDF4-python` library directly:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

f = Dataset('test.nc', mode='w')
f.createDimension("Step", nsteps)
f.createDimension("time", ntimes)
d = f.createVariable("d", "f4",("Step", "time"))

#Computatation
for i in range(num_steps):
    d[i, :] = i
```

I assume your computation is more complicated than your example so you may think of replacing `= i` with something that uses xarray/dask.

Comment: I suspected that that might be the case, but @shoyer's answer seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @shoyer is correct that xarray can write chunked arrays to disk. Honestly, my impression was that xarray was calling dask's compute method before writing arrays but I appear to be mistaken. If you can provide a slightly more detailed explanation of what your computation step does, I'll happily update my answer.

Comment: Is there a problem with the current simple example computation step that makes it problematic to implement the example using xarray? I understand that I could achieve this using netCDF4-python, as you described, but I would prefer to understand how to do it using xarray, if possible.

Comment: Yes, as my comment describes, dask-array's do not support item assignment so you couldn't write `d[i, :] = i` if `d` is an dask array or a DataArray using dask array under the hood.

Comment: I have updated my question with a more realistic example.

Comment: This seems to straightforward that I wonder why xarray doesn't support doing similarly? Is there a catch to updating xarrays manually per netCDF4?