# Writing xarray multiindex data in chunks

Tags: python, arrays, dask, parquet, python-xarray

I am trying to efficiently restructure a large multidimentional dataset. Let assume I have a number of remotely sensed images over time with a number of bands with coordinates x y for pixel location, time for time of image acquisition, and band for different data collected.

In my use case lets assume the xarray coord lengths are roughly x (3000), y (3000), time (10), with bands (40) of floating point data. So 100gb+ of data.

I have been trying to work from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951981/create-and-write-xarray-dataarray-to-netcdf-in-chunks) but I am having trouble translating it to this case.

### Small dataset example

NOTE: the actual data is much larger than this example.

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import xarray as xr

nrows = 100
ncols = 200
row_chunks = 50
col_chunks = 50

data = da.random.random(size=(1, nrows, ncols), chunks=(1, row_chunks, col_chunks))

def create_band(data, x, y, band_name):

    return xr.DataArray(data,
                        dims=('band', 'y', 'x'),
                        coords={'band': [band_name],
                                'y': y,
                                'x': x})

def create_coords(data, left, top, celly, cellx):
    nrows = data.shape[-2]
    ncols = data.shape[-1]
    right = left + cellx*ncols
    bottom = top - celly*nrows
    x = np.linspace(left, right, ncols) + cellx/2.0
    y = np.linspace(top, bottom, nrows) - celly/2.0
    
    return x, y

x, y = create_coords(data, 1000, 2000, 30, 30)

src = []

for time in ['t1', 't2', 't3']:

    src_t = xr.concat([create_band(data, x, y, band) for band in ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir']], dim='band')\
                    .expand_dims(dim='time')\
                    .assign_coords({'time': [time]})
    
    src.append(src_t)

src = xr.concat(src, dim='time')

print(src)


<xarray.DataArray 'random_sample-5840d8564d778d573dd403f27c3f47a5' (time: 3, band: 4, y: 100, x: 200)>
dask.array<concatenate, shape=(3, 4, 100, 200), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 1, 50, 50), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 1.015e+03 1.045e+03 1.075e+03 ... 6.985e+03 7.015e+03
  * band     (band) object 'blue' 'green' 'red' 'nir'
  * y        (y) float64 1.985e+03 1.955e+03 1.924e+03 ... -984.7 -1.015e+03
  * time     (time) object 't1' 't2' 't3'
```

### Restructured - stacked and transposed

I need to store the output of the following:

```py
print(src.stack(sample=('y','x','time')).T)

<xarray.DataArray 'random_sample-5840d8564d778d573dd403f27c3f47a5' (sample: 60000, band: 4)>
dask.array<transpose, shape=(60000, 4), dtype=float64, chunksize=(3600, 1), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) object 'blue' 'green' 'red' 'nir'
  * sample   (sample) MultiIndex
  - y        (sample) float64 1.985e+03 1.985e+03 ... -1.015e+03 -1.015e+03
  - x        (sample) float64 1.015e+03 1.015e+03 ... 7.015e+03 7.015e+03
  - time     (sample) object 't1' 't2' 't3' 't1' 't2' ... 't3' 't1' 't2' 't3'
```

I am hoping to use dask and xarray to write the result to disk in chunks, accessible for [open_mfdataset](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html#reading-and-writing-data).
parquet seems like a good option, but I can't figure out how to write it in chunks (src is too big to store in memory).

```py
@dask.delayed
def stacker(data):
   return data.stack(sample=('y','x','time')).T.to_pandas() 

stacker(src).to_parquet('out_*.parquet')

def stack_write(data):
   data.stack(sample=('y','x','time')).T.to_pandas().to_parquet('out_*.parquet')
   return None

stack_write(src)
```

At this point I am just hoping for some good ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Is ```src``` stored in memory before "stacked and transposed" operation ?

Comment: @Rivers No it is not. Should be done lazily in chunks by dask.

Comment: Ok I see. And have you already completed this "stack and transpose"  operation successfully ? Or is it impossble to complete it successfully precisely because of the fact that ```src``` is too big to store in memory ?

Comment: @Rivers no too big to complete, hence storing chunks.

Comment: In what consists your dataset ? Is it for example one big netcdf file of 100gb, or multiple ```.nc``` files or something else ? And in this case, how do you load the data (code/function used) ? Or do you create a dask array from code like in your example with ```dask.array.random``` ?

Comment: I have 6 years of satellite imagery with 40 bands for each year.  The code example above can be used to create something with the same structure.

Comment: Thanks. I'm asking because it will make a big difference for the rest of the code (we won't be able to proceed in the same ways). Could you show the line of code with which you load the data ? (I'll be very busy  in the coming days so I'll be able to answer next week)

Comment: Im using geowombat which makes an xarray from the tiffs `with gw.open(tifs, time_names = time_names, chunks=400) as ds:`

Comment: In the example you provided, does ```src``` corresponds to the ```ds``` object ? If so, is it just before you try to stack and transpose ? What is the exact type of ```ds``` ? Is it a ```xarray.Dataset``` ? Is it "dask-backed" (from your it seems it is, but the ```src``` of your example is not "dask-backed", it make a huge difference) ?

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution here (https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1077#issuecomment-644803374) for writing multiindexed datasets to file.

You'll have to manually "encode" the dataset into a form that can be written as netCDF. And then "decode" when you read it back.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr


def encode_multiindex(ds, idxname):
    encoded = ds.reset_index(idxname)
    coords = dict(zip(ds.indexes[idxname].names, ds.indexes[idxname].levels))
    for coord in coords:
        encoded[coord] = coords[coord].values
    shape = [encoded.sizes[coord] for coord in coords]
    encoded[idxname] = np.ravel_multi_index(ds.indexes[idxname].codes, shape)
    encoded[idxname].attrs["compress"] = " ".join(ds.indexes[idxname].names)
    return encoded


def decode_to_multiindex(encoded, idxname):
    names = encoded[idxname].attrs["compress"].split(" ")
    shape = [encoded.sizes[dim] for dim in names]
    indices = np.unravel_index(encoded.landpoint.values, shape)
    arrays = [encoded[dim].values[index] for dim, index in zip(names, indices)]
    mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)

    decoded = xr.Dataset({}, {idxname: mindex})
    for varname in encoded.data_vars:
        if idxname in encoded[varname].dims:
            decoded[varname] = (idxname, encoded[varname].values)
    return decoded
```

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. Any thoughts on writing to the hdf in chunks?

Comment: Nothing except "don't do it". HDF in parallel is messy. Zarr is a better option, it works well with parallel writes and xarray/dask. You can then convert the zarr to HDF.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the solution, for the moment, but a version of your code, modifed so that it will be easily reproducible if others want to try to solve this problem:

The problem is with the `stack` operation (`concatenated.stack(sample=('y','x','time')`).
At this step, the memory keeps increasing and the process is `killed`.

The `concatenated` object is a "Dask-backed" `xarray.DataArray`. So we could expect the `stack` operation to be done lazily by Dask. So, why is the process `killed` at this step ?

2 possibilities for what is happening here:

- The `stack` operation is in fact done lazily by Dask, but because the data are very that huge, even the minimum required memory for Dask is too much
- The `stack` operation is NOT Dask-backed

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import xarray as xr
from numpy.random import RandomState

nrows = 20000
ncols = 20000
row_chunks = 500
col_chunks = 500


# Create a reproducible random numpy array
prng = RandomState(1234567890)
numpy_array = prng.rand(1, nrows, ncols)

data = da.from_array(numpy_array, chunks=(1, row_chunks, col_chunks))


def create_band(data, x, y, band_name):

    return xr.DataArray(data,
                        dims=('band', 'y', 'x'),
                        coords={'band': [band_name],
                                'y': y,
                                'x': x})

def create_coords(data, left, top, celly, cellx):
    nrows = data.shape[-2]
    ncols = data.shape[-1]
    right = left + cellx*ncols
    bottom = top - celly*nrows
    x = np.linspace(left, right, ncols) + cellx/2.0
    y = np.linspace(top, bottom, nrows) - celly/2.0
    
    return x, y


x, y = create_coords(data, 1000, 2000, 30, 30)

bands = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir']
times = ['t1', 't2', 't3']
bands_list = [create_band(data, x, y, band) for band in bands]

src = []

for time in times:

    src_t = xr.concat(bands_list, dim='band')\
                    .expand_dims(dim='time')\
                    .assign_coords({'time': [time]})

    src.append(src_t)


concatenated = xr.concat(src, dim='time')
print(concatenated)
# computed = concatenated.compute() # "computed" is ~35.8GB

stacked = concatenated.stack(sample=('y','x','time'))

transposed = stacked.T
```

One can try to change the values of `nrows` and `ncols` in order to vary the size of `concatenated`. And for performance we could/should vary the `chunks` too.

Note: I even tried this

```
concatenated.to_netcdf("concatenated.nc")
concatenated = xr.open_dataarray("concatenated.nc", chunks=10)
```

This is in order to be sure it's a Dask-backed DataArray and to be able to adjust the chunks too.
I tried different value/s for `chunks`: but always out of memory.