# Xarray: out-of-memory error (when calling the stack method of a Dask-backed Xarray the task is being killed by the system)

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I was trying to solve a question of a SO post ([Writing xarray multiindex data in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906769/writing-xarray-multiindex-data-in-chunks/)) and I ended with the code I provide below.

The problem is that in this code the call to the `stack` method of the `DataArray` results in an out of memory error.

**My question is:**

I'm wondering why the stack method of the `concatenated` object (which is a `xarray.DataArray`) can't complete successfully, even though this DataArray is backed by Dask (so it should not run out of memory) ? Why does the test machine runs out of memory and the task is killed by the system ?

**A little summary of what is happening when running this code:**

The code runs smoothly until the line `stacked = concatenated.stack(sample=('y','x','time'))`.

At this this moment, the memory usage keeps increasing until it reaches almost 100% and the task is killed by the system.
The code was executed on a machine with 8GB of RAM.
I thought it would not run out of memory because `concatenated` is a Dask-backed `xarray. DataArray`. But it does.

I made various changes to this code, like using delayed operations, changing chunks sizes, using Dask method instead of xarray's, etc. but without success

**I thought about two possibilities of what is happening:**

- The stack operation is NOT Dask-backed
- The stack operation is Dask-backed, but even Dask requires a minimum amount of memory (for each chunk) and this amount can't fit in memory

Does someone know what is happening here and how to solve this problem ?

**END NOTES:**

You can vary `nrows` and `ncols` in order to change the size of `concatenated`.
For example setting `nrows = 10000` instead of `nrows = 20000` will reduce its size by half.

To be sure that the DataArray is Dask-backed I also tried to save `concatenated` to netcdf and load it with the `chunks` parameter. I tried different values for the chunks, but again without success:

```
concatenated.to_netcdf("concatenated.nc")
concatenated = xr.open_dataarray("concatenated.nc", chunks=10)
```

Using smaller values for the `chunks` parameter only results in taking
more time to run out of memory.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import xarray as xr
from numpy.random import RandomState

nrows = 20000
ncols = 20000
row_chunks = 500
col_chunks = 500


# Create a reproducible random numpy array
prng = RandomState(1234567890)
numpy_array = prng.rand(1, nrows, ncols)

data = da.from_array(numpy_array, chunks=(1, row_chunks, col_chunks))


def create_band(data, x, y, band_name):

    return xr.DataArray(data,
                        dims=('band', 'y', 'x'),
                        coords={'band': [band_name],
                                'y': y,
                                'x': x})

def create_coords(data, left, top, celly, cellx):
    nrows = data.shape[-2]
    ncols = data.shape[-1]
    right = left + cellx*ncols
    bottom = top - celly*nrows
    x = np.linspace(left, right, ncols) + cellx/2.0
    y = np.linspace(top, bottom, nrows) - celly/2.0
    
    return x, y


x, y = create_coords(data, 1000, 2000, 30, 30)

bands = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir']
times = ['t1', 't2', 't3']
bands_list = [create_band(data, x, y, band) for band in bands]

src = []

for time in times:

    src_t = xr.concat(bands_list, dim='band')\
                    .expand_dims(dim='time')\
                    .assign_coords({'time': [time]})

    src.append(src_t)


concatenated = xr.concat(src, dim='time')
print(concatenated)
# computed = concatenated.compute() # "computed" is ~35.8GB

# All is fine until here
stacked = concatenated.stack(sample=('y','x','time'))

# After stack we'd like to transpose
transposed = stacked.T
```

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I have a similar problem with stack

Comment: No, didn't have enough time. My guess, but that's just a guess, I didn't have the time to take a deeper look, is what I wrote in my question as the 2nd possibility: because of the size of the data, even a `chunk` is too big to fit in memory, so the only option would be to run it on a machine with enough memory. If you find an other solution please keep us up-to-date!

Comment: Actually I was more prone to believe your 1st possibility because this problem doesn't occur to me with every xarray function. Unless stack inherently requires more memory than other methods and thus even the single chunk asks for too much memory.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/4113