# Dask implementation for mutation operation

Tags: python, distributed-computing, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to convert the following numpy operation in dask but the thing it is a mutable operation so getting `NotImplementedError: Item assignment with <class 'tuple'> not supported` error in the `distMap[:, i] = da.sqrt(xSum + ySum).min(axis=0)` statement.
Following is the code:

```
for i, mask in enumerate(masks): 
     bounds = find_boundaries(mask, mode='inner')
     X2, Y2 = np.nonzero(bounds)
     X2 = da.from_array(X2, 'auto')
     Y2 = da.from_array(Y2, 'auto')
     xSum = (X2.reshape(-1, 1) - X1.reshape(1, -1)) ** 2
     ySum = (Y2.reshape(-1, 1) - Y1.reshape(1, -1)) ** 2
     distMap[:, i] = da.sqrt(xSum + ySum).min(axis=0)
```

I checked this answer ([Item assignment to Python dask array objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142892/item-assignment-to-python-dask-array-objects)) and it is telling an approach which honestly, I am not able to understand.Also, there is also a mention of `da.where` approach but I am not able to find any literature on it further.
How to do it?